# What's the issue with this 9-png , showing black borders?

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

[image]

I have been struggling for a week to run this nine patch image by adding patches to it with all case but it doesn't work , I can't figure out why ? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

It shouldn't show black lines when I am using it.

This is the layout code where I use this image ,

```
                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/answerA"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/d_grey"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="AnswerCheck" />
```

--Edit--

As suggested in an answer I opened this image in ninepatch tool and below is the screenshot for the same,

[image]

Comment: did u save it as .9.png?

Comment: create new folder in Res called drawable-nodpi 
and place your image on it,this solved my problem ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- Have you created 9-patch images properly? [check out this site](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)
  and create 9patch image.
- Do not remove .9 extension from image like sample.9.png
- Do not resize image after creating 9 patch image.
- Refresh-Clean-build project to apply changes you made in resource
  folders

Comment: Hey I tried this tool and its great I want to know how do I stop the area with D text from stretching.

Comment: If you are using android asset studio tool provided by above link then, you only have to make sure the Text part in image is inside center rectangle.. i.e.  inside rectangle part will remain unstretched

Comment: Look let me make it clear the above written D in the image is part of image and there is no text anywhere at all , Now when this image gets streched then D is also getting stretched but I don't want this to happen.

Comment: I know that D is a image part.. I thought I was clear, but. well... take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbsTn0a9y2s) it shows both to create 9 patch and apply padding.. So in first part around 0:08 you will notice inside rect part which I commented before..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your drawing, my guess is that you have far too many patches, probably around 18 patches instead of the usual 9.

Load the nine-patch into the [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) tool (which is in your Android sdk under `tools/`)

- Then select > `Show bad patches`

**Update:**

Take a look at this image (taken from this technical [blog](http://www.techjini.com/blog/nine-patch-images-useful-for-android-2/))

[image: nine patch diagram]

For me at least, that's what I envisioned a 9-patch to be, that there were 9 patches in the png. In your latest drawing however from inside the draw-9-patches tool, I think I'm counting 20 patches

That being said, I'm not sure if what I'm saying is correct. If you have bad 9-patch, the tool should at least be showing you the bad patches surrounded by red lines. And so, it could be that both the blogger and myself are incorrect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for ur reply , I have added an image screenshot of what I see in ninepatch tool , where are the bad patches here or which are those ? How do you figure out 18 patches ?

Comment: May be I made a mistake, but click on the button "Show bad patches" in your screenshot.

Comment: Clicking on this button doesn't change anything , does it mean I don't have any bad patches ?

Answer (score 0):

I often encountered this issue also and I usually avoid to put the back line on the very edge of the image.
Try to do it as you did it on the bottom of your image and leave at least 1 pixel on each edge without black otherwise it is not correctly rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on a xxxhdpi screen. Android doc says for xxxhdpi: "Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi). Use this for the launcher icon only, see note above." In my xxxhdpi device, the 9-patch image was displayed with the black lines borders because of that. When removing the xxxhdpi 9-patch, the display issue was fixed.