# Why this strange border around ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I am getting strange border around my ImageView after updating android studio. The drawables are nine patch images. And they were not there on the previous gradle builds. Also I am testing this on an API 17 device.

[image: Normal ImageView]

[image: Also getting it around some map markers]

Here is the layout segment for the first arrow ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_imgarrow"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/slide_next"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/splash_img"
    android:layout_below="@id/splash_img"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the issue with this 9-png , showing black borders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336747/whats-the-issue-with-this-9-png-showing-black-borders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a workaround but still not sure why it happened after update. I switched from using 9 patch image to regular drawables. Now the problem is solved. May be it was due to some bad patches.